# "witadmin destroyid" command does not work with multiple ids

Tags: tfs

Despite the documentation indicating that multiple work item IDs can be added in a comma-delimited list, whenever I try the following command I get an error:

```
witadmin destroywi /collection:<my collection url> /id:134,135
```

results in:

```
TF212000: 135 is not a valid argument for this command
```

If I execute the same command on a single id (including the one it is complaining about specifically) everything works fine. Here is the documentation for the widadmin destroywi command:

```
Usage: witadmin destroywi /collection:collectionurl /id:id [/noprompt]

 /collection    Specifies the Team Foundation project collection. Use a fully specified URL such as
                http://servername:8080/tfs/Collection0.
 /id            Specifies the ID of the work item to destroy.  Supports multiple IDs delimited by commas such as
                12,15,23 (with no whitespace).
 /noprompt      Turns off the confirmation message.
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a bug in witadmin?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks for fixing it, sorry about that!

Comment: Does it work if you surround with quotes: `\id:"12,13"` ?

Comment: @DaveShaw it does! Thanks! I'm not sure why they don't put that in the documentation. If you write that up as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the values passed to the `/id` switch in double-quotes to get the command line to consider it as one argument instead of two:

```
/id:"12,13,14"
```

Otherwise it gets passed as `/id:12 13` - where 13 is a separate parameter (hence the error).

Answer (score 0):

If you leave a space between 134, and 135 you'll get that kind of error.

Comment: Yeah I read the documentation, and as you can see in my post I don't have a space in between numbers